# NextJS api folder return Internal Server Error

Tags: webpack, next.js

How can I determine the type of blocker when I add API middleware plugin inside `api/` folder with NextJS Library.

I have 2 mirror servers with different subdomain; the first ONE is working well and return the response from API call. However, the second one is not and it returns any result else Internal Server Error.

I have tried to ignore the `api/` folder and use the `next.config.js` recommended like below:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: 'https://subdomain.domain.com/api/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
```

But unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean the "type of blocker"?

Comment: i need to know if that blocker blocking from the server of api or from the server of the next application